# How do I get the last 5 elements, excluding the first element from an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

In a JavaScript array, how do I get the last 5 elements, *excluding the first element*?

```
[1, 55, 77, 88] // ...would return [55, 77, 88]
```

---

*adding additional examples:*

```
[1, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44] // ...would return [88, 99, 22, 33, 44]

[1] // ...would return []
```

Answer (score 505, accepted):

You can call:

```
arr.slice(Math.max(arr.length - 5, 1))
```

If you don't want to exclude the first element, use

```
arr.slice(Math.max(arr.length - 5, 0))
```

Answer (score 141):

Here is one I haven't seen that's even shorter

```
arr.slice(1).slice(-5)
```

Run the code snippet below for proof of it doing what you want

```js
const arr = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    arr.push(i);
    console.log(`Array ${i + 1}: ${arr} -> ${arr.slice(1).slice(-5)}`);
}
```

Another way to do it would be using lodash https://lodash.com/docs#rest - that is of course if you don't mind having to load a huge JavaScript minified file if you're trying to do it from your browser.

```
_.slice(_.rest(arr), -5)
```

Answer (score 44):

If you are using lodash, its even simpler with [takeRight](https://lodash.com/docs#takeRight).

`_.takeRight(arr, 5);`

Comment: It also take care of if the array has less than 5 elements

Comment: Does this skip over the first element?

Answer (score 16):

```js
var y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

console.log(y.slice((y.length - 5), y.length))
```

you can do this!

Comment: This is the same as: y.slice(- 5)

Comment: The question also is not just about `slice`. For single element arrays, it should not return anything, which is currently unaccounted for in this answer.

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
var array = [1, 55, 77, 88, 76, 59];
var array_last_five;
array_last_five = array.slice(-5);
if (array.length < 6) {
     array_last_five.shift();
}
```

Comment: Again, it's not about *worry*. The main point of SO is to provide answers to specific user questions. Your original answer did not. In fact, your update still does not meet the spec.

Comment: I beg to differ. It does exactly what he asked for: returns the last five, and shifts it over one if the first one is included in the end result. The shift is to make sure that we remove the first one if it is included. It also returns the exact same thing as SLaks answer, even if the total is less than five.

Comment: -1 Your code is 6 lines when it only needs to be 2 lines at most (the array and the and how to get what the user wants). Not only does your answer not meet the spec it is also overly complicated for no reason and still wrong.

Answer (score 5):

ES6 way:

I use [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) for array to get `first` and remaining `rest` elements and then I'll take last five of the `rest` with [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method:

```js
const cutOffFirstAndLastFive = (array) => {
  const [first, ...rest] = array;
  return rest.slice(-5);
}

cutOffFirstAndLastFive([1, 55, 77, 88]);

console.log(
  'Tests:',
  JSON.stringify(cutOffFirstAndLastFive([1, 55, 77, 88])),
  JSON.stringify(cutOffFirstAndLastFive([1, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44])),
  JSON.stringify(cutOffFirstAndLastFive([1]))
);
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it in one line like this:

```js
const y = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
const lastX = 5;
const res = y.filter((val, index, arr) => index > arr.length - lastX - 1);
    
console.log(res);
```

```
.filter((val, index, arr) => index > arr.length - 6)
```

Answer (score 0):

Beginner solution:

```
var givme = function(n) {
    if(n.length == 1) {
        return [];
    }
    if(n.length > 5) {
        return n.slice(n.length-5, n.length);
    }
    if(n.length <= 5) {
       return n.slice(1, n.length);
    }
}

// console.log(givme([1, 55, 77, 88, 99, 22, 33, 44]));
```

Comment: Some critiques: The middle condition is just `slice(-5)`. The last condition is just `slice(1)`. The first condition is unnecessary. While not strictly necessary, it's generally good to use `else if` to show related conditions too. Lastly, `var givme = function(n)` is just `function givme(n)`.

Answer (score -2):

```
array.reverse()
     .slice(0,5)
     .reverse()  //if you wanna keep the order of last 5
```

---

```
const myOriginalArray = [...Array(10).keys()] //making an array of numbers

const instanceFromlastFiveItemsOfMyArray = [
    ...myOriginalArray.reverse().slice(0,5).reverse()
    ]
```

Comment: Copy-paste? What are you talking about? **1.** The first `reverse` reverses the original array. **2.** `slice` shallow-copies the array and makes a new one. **3.** The second `reverse` reverses the sliced array, but not the original. This means that `array` stays reversed when this is done. If you want proof, [Try it online.](https://tio.run/##XY3LCoNADEX3fsXdqRDFPuxL@iWli1FjsQxOyQxCv36qDnVhVuGe5Ny3GpVtpP@4rFY162wwLXvfmME6KBH1xR2PgrAj7AkHwpFQEk6EM@FCuE6oeFbR/GE059q8krjmzgjfYgqKNGAHq/uG28m4xLnwyGI5SSPMky84Kaj8B@vBxq86x4Ktf8WhZsZhSyvvfw "JavaScript (Babel Node) – Try It Online")

Comment: You should probably read [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse#description). `reverse` mutates the array that it is called on. If you're dead set on using `reverse` to solve this, you'll have to clone the array, then do what you did. That this is essentially 2 O(n) operations, where it can easily be done in 1, like the above solutions.

Comment: Oh, and it fails to meet the condition in the question "excluding the first element."