# Issue with for loop in iterating the last 5 objects in reverse order

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have one json array. Now I need to display on my UI such that it displays only the last 5 json objects in reverse order. If the length of the array is less than 5 it should display all those same in reverse order.

Now I was successful in displaying the last 5 if the length is greater than 5. But if the array size is less than 5 my logic is not working. How can we fix this. Can someone help

```
for (var i = response.length - 1 ; i >= response.length-5 ; --i) {
        var date = new Date(response[i].transactiondate);
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var dt = date.getDate();
        response[i].transactiondate = dt + '-' + month + '-' + year;
        outputdata += '<br>' + response[i].transactiondate + '&nbsp;' + response[i].amount + '&nbsp;' + response[i].description;
}
```

Comment: take a look at this, https://stackoverflow.com/a/6473869/4921471

Comment: Instead of trying to set up a reverse loop, just reverse your array. `array.reverse()`

Comment: you can make the condition `i >= response.length-5 && i >= 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Add a condition for your case
var start = (response.length >=5) ? response.length-5 : 0;

for (var i = response.length - 1 ; i >= start ; --i) {
        var date = new Date(response[i].transactiondate);
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var dt = date.getDate();
        response[i].transactiondate = dt + '-' + month + '-' + year;
        outputdata += '<br>' + response[i].transactiondate + '&nbsp;' + response[i].amount + '&nbsp;' + response[i].description;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could check if `i` is greater or equal as zero as well.

```
for (var i = response.length - 1; i >= response.length - 5 && i >= 0; --i) {
```

or use a variable for the lower bound

```
var min = response.length > 5 ? response.length - 5 : 0;

for (var i = response.length - 1; i >= min; --i) {
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `reverse()` and `splice()` functions respectively

```
response=response.reverse();
response=response.splice(5);
```

Now this response object will contain last five records in reverse order. now you just need to iterate this.

```
for(i=0;i<response.lenth;i++)
{
     //Your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the one of the solution. I have updated original array, where you can keep original array as it is :

```js
response = response.slice(-5).reverse();

for (var i = 0 ; i < response.length ; i++) {
 var date = new Date(response[i].transactiondate);
        var year = date.getFullYear();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
        var dt = date.getDate();
        response[i].transactiondate = dt + '-' + month + '-' + year;
        outputdata += '<br>' + response[i].transactiondate + '&nbsp;' + response[i].amount + '&nbsp;' + response[i].description;
}
```