# Getting last x elements in array not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Trying to use the answer from here:
[In a javascript array, how do I get the last 5 elements, excluding the first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473858/in-a-javascript-array-how-do-i-get-the-last-5-elements-excluding-the-first-ele)

I am using express / node.

I have

```
var texts = [{"id":1, "content":"one"}, {"id":2, "content":"two"},{"id":3, "content":"three", "id":4, "content":"four"];
```

In my get request, I tried responding like this:

```
app.get('/api/texts/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json(texts.slice(3, 1));
    next();
});
```

but this responds with [] and nothing else. Any idea why?

edit:

```
app.get('/api/texts/', function (req, res, next) {
    res.json(texts);
    next();
});
```

The above properly prints out all the elements inside `texts`. It's just when I change it to `res.json(texts.slice(3,1));` it prints out `[]`.

Comment: `1` is less than `3`

Comment: @Andy I push elements to the array with push requests before using doing the get request.

Comment: `[...'12345'].slice(3,1)//[]` What is the expected result? To get the last N indexes  of an array, excluding the first index of the array?

Comment: Use a for loop... Come on!

Comment: @Andy See my edit

Comment: The marked answer in your linked question uses `Math.max` to choose one number from two numbers. Your code doesn't do that.

Comment: @Andy Totally missed that. That's probably the issue. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array.slice(x,y) cant have an x < y. it will always return an empty array.