# How to show the last 2 elements of an array based on createdAt

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to show the 2 previous recent comments based on createdAt, by implementing this filterMethod

```
const filterComments = props.comments.slice(0, inc).sort((a, b) => {
    const date1 = new Date(a.createdAt) as any;
    const date2 = new Date(b.createdAt) as any;
    return date1 - date2;
});
```

`inc` is variable that increments if user selects showMore

which isn't anything special

```
  const showMoreComments = () => {
        return filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <CommentListContainer comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
            </div>
        ));
    };
```

The problem is if the comments has more than 2 comments, the filtering gets out of order, s**o by default if there just 2 comments filterComments shows the recent 2 comments which works as i expect**, but if there are more than 2 comments and i click on show more comments, it stops filtering correctly.

I've tried this method `arr.slice(Math.max(arr.length - 5, 1))`

[In a javascript array, how do I get the last 5 elements, excluding the first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473858/in-a-javascript-array-how-do-i-get-the-last-5-elements-excluding-the-first-ele)

but its not really the answer i was looking for, i think this could be a reducer issue, or something.

What could i be doing wrong

*showMoreMethod*

```
  const showComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inc + 2 && inc <= the_comments) {
            setShowMore(inc + 2);
            setShowLessFlag(true);
        } else {
            setShowMore(the_comments);
        }
    };
```

**CommentList.tsx**

```
import React, { Fragment, useState } from "react";
import Grid from "@material-ui/core/Grid";
import OurSecondaryButton from "../../../common/OurSecondaryButton";
import CommentListContainer from "../commentListContainer/commentListContainer";
import storeHooks from "../../../common/storeHooks";

function CommentList(props: any) {
    const [showMore, setShowMore] = useState<Number>(2);
    const [openModal, setOpenModal] = useState(false);
    const [showLessFlag, setShowLessFlag] = useState<Boolean>(false);
    const the_comments = props.comments.length;
    const inc = showMore as any;
    const min = Math.min(2, the_comments - inc);
    const showComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        if (inc + 2 && inc <= the_comments) {
            setShowMore(inc + 2);
            setShowLessFlag(true);
        } else {
            setShowMore(the_comments);
        }
    };
    const handleClickOpen = () => {
        setOpenModal(true);
    };
    const handleCloseModal = () => {
        setOpenModal(false);
    };

    const showLessComments = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShowMore(2);
        setShowLessFlag(false);
    };
    const isBold = (comment) => {
        return comment.userId === props.userId ? 800 : 400;
    };

    const filterComments = props.comments.slice(0, inc).sort((a, b) => {
        const date1 = new Date(a.createdAt) as any;
        const date2 = new Date(b.createdAt) as any;
        return date1 - date2;
    });

    const showMoreComments = () => {
        return filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
            <div key={i}>
                <CommentListContainer comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
            </div>
        ));
    };

    return (
        <Grid>
            <Fragment>
                <div style={{ margin: "30px 0px" }}>
                    {props.comments.length > 2 ? (
                        <Fragment>
                            {min !== -1 ? (
                                <Fragment>
                                    {min !== 0 ? (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            View {min !== -1 ? min : 0} More Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    ) : (
                                        <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                            Show Less Comments
                                        </OurSecondaryButton>
                                    )}
                                </Fragment>
                            ) : (
                                <OurSecondaryButton onClick={(e) => showLessComments(e)} component="span" color="secondary">
                                    Show Less Comments
                                </OurSecondaryButton>
                            )}
                        </Fragment>
                    ) : null}
                </div>
            </Fragment>
            {showLessFlag === true ? (
                // will show most recent comments below
                showMoreComments()
            ) : (
                <Fragment>
                    {/* filter based on first comment  */}
                    {filterComments.map((comment, i) => (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <CommentListContainer comment={comment} openModal={openModal} handleCloseModal={handleCloseModal} isBold={isBold} handleClickOpen={handleClickOpen} {...props} />
                        </div>
                    ))}
                </Fragment>
            )}
        </Grid>
    );
}
// prevents un-necesary re renders
export default React.memo(CommentList);
```

**reducer** Reducer that handles the new state

```
 case types.COMMENT_UPDATES_SUCCESS:
    console.log(action);
    const findCommentKey2 = state.posts.findIndex((x) => x.id === action.payload.comment.postId);
    console.log(findCommentKey2);
    draft.posts[findCommentKey2].Comments = [
        action.payload.comment,
        // add comment first, then sort it out by the most recent comment
        ...draft.posts[findCommentKey2].Comments,
    ];
    return;
```

**comment shape**

```
[
  {
    "id": 177,
    "comment_body": "",
    "gifUrl": "https://media0.giphy.com/media/LRNxdA0soqs09YWa4F/giphy.gif?cid=e8452e68d3e94d3464efb70e1059fae80209a6b531b30b7d&rid=giphy.gif",
    "userId": 9,
    "postId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-05-24T21:11:07.939Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-24T21:11:07.939Z",
    "author": {
      "username": "barnowl",
      "gravatar": "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png",
      "bio": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 178,
    "comment_body": "",
    "gifUrl": "https://media2.giphy.com/media/xThtalTQnCNEatzgUU/giphy.gif?cid=e8452e68d3e94d3464efb70e1059fae80209a6b531b30b7d&rid=giphy.gif",
    "userId": 9,
    "postId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-05-24T21:11:28.971Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-24T21:11:28.971Z",
    "author": {
      "username": "barnowl",
      "gravatar": "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png",
      "bio": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 179,
    "comment_body": "fsfsfssfsf",
    "gifUrl": "",
    "userId": 9,
    "postId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-05-24T21:12:31.920Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-24T21:12:31.920Z",
    "author": {
      "username": "barnowl",
      "gravatar": "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png",
      "bio": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 175,
    "comment_body": "fsfsfsfsfsf",
    "gifUrl": "",
    "userId": 9,
    "postId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-05-24T21:10:56.303Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-24T21:10:56.303Z",
    "author": {
      "username": "barnowl",
      "gravatar": "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png",
      "bio": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 176,
    "comment_body": "",
    "gifUrl": "https://media3.giphy.com/media/Jrl4FlTaymFFbNiwU5/giphy.gif?cid=e8452e68f6a75bf1f94a134a15ab35ff1b0a09e2d060e1da&rid=giphy.gif",
    "userId": 9,
    "postId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-05-24T21:11:01.152Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-24T21:11:01.152Z",
    "author": {
      "username": "barnowl",
      "gravatar": "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png",
      "bio": null
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 180,
    "comment_body": "fssfsffsf",
    "gifUrl": "",
    "userId": 9,
    "postId": 15,
    "createdAt": "2020-05-24T21:12:58.086Z",
    "updatedAt": "2020-05-24T21:12:58.086Z",
    "author": {
      "username": "barnowl",
      "gravatar": "https://api.adorable.io/avatars/400/bf1eed82fbe37add91cb4192e4d14de6.png",
      "bio": null
    }
  }
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you sort them first before actually slicing them?

You can first use `slice(0)` to clone the original array, as `sort()` sorts the elements locally (and you shouldn't do that over the state).

This works for me:

```js
const comments = [{createdAt: '2020-01-20'},{ createdAt: '2019-01-01'},{createdAt: '2019-05-01'},{createdAt: '2019-05-06'}];

const inc = 2;

const filterComments = comments.slice(0).sort((a, b) => {
    const date1 = new Date(a.createdAt);
    const date2 = new Date(b.createdAt);
    return date2 - date1;
}).slice(0, inc);

console.log(filterComments);
```

Comment: thank you Pablo, but the problem is props.comments is derived from an immutable selector, so i will get this error `TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property '0' of object '[object Array]'`

Comment: its a decendant from this.props.posts which comes from a redux selector, that was the reason why i sliced first, then sorted.

Comment: So should i do comments.slice(0)... then the rest of the logic.

Comment: But if you slice first, you will only sort the ones you're already filtering. The sorting should always happen on the total of elements, then you should restrict the results as much as you want. A better option is to ensure that the comments will be always obtained sorted, so you can feel sure you can take the first `inc` elements.

Comment: What you say about immutable is correct, as `sort()` sorts locally. You should get a copy then of the comments before sorting them. For doing that, you can just do `props.comments.slice(0)` as you suggest.

Comment: let me try that out.

Comment: this isn't sorting properly, i will share comment data shape. It should by default show the 2 recent comments, and upon show more comments, it will show the most recent 2 comments. Should i change the reducer case