# How to get las X elements/elements propertie from an object in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

Got an object like this

```
var flightInfo = [
    { id: 01, departure: "Barcelona", arrival: "Madrid", price: 100, scale: false},
    { id: 02, departure:  "Brussels", arrival: "La Habana", price: 500, scale: true},
    { id: 03, departure: "Madrid", arrival: "Bangkok", price: 1000, scale: false},
    { id: 04, departure: "Los Angeles", arrival: "Sydney", price: 1500, scale: true},
    { id: 05, departure: "Berlin", arrival: "Melbourne", price: 1100, scale: true},
    { id: 06, departure: "Jakarta", arrival: "Manila", price: 400, scale: false},
    { id: 07, departure: "Chiang Mai", arrival: "Phuket", price: 80, scale: false},
    { id: 08, departure: "Minsk", arrival: "Washington D.C", price: 100, scale: true},
    { id: 09, departure: "Bilbao", arrival: "Buenos Aires", price: 700, scale: false},
    { id: 10, departure: "Quatar", arrival: "Madrid", price: 300, scale: false},
]
```

I would like to get last 5 elements and/or properties of each element, I succeed pushing into an array a requested property of each element iterating it from start to end, but I'm failing doing it reverse to a determined number. No need to say that object length may vary. Here is my last attempt:

```
function getLast5FlightsArrivals(){
    var last5FlightsArrivals = {};
    for (i=flightInfo.length-1; i >= flightInfo-6; i--){
        last5FlightsArrivals.push(flightInfo[i].arrival)
    }
    return last5FlightsArrivals;
}
```

But I'm always getting an empty object as response on the console: Object{}, cannot see where is the error or what I'm doing wrong, just a noob trying to lear
Hope someone could bring some ligh. Thanks in advance!

Comment: slice with negative index will work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In a javascript array, how do I get the last 5 elements, excluding the first element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6473858/in-a-javascript-array-how-do-i-get-the-last-5-elements-excluding-the-first-ele)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) with negative integer, it will pick value starting from end

```js
console.log([1,2,3,4].slice(-2))
console.log([].slice(-2))
```

Comment: Thank you for ur reply as well!! Worked it smoothly!

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```js
var flightInfo = [
    { id: 01, departure: "Barcelona", arrival: "Madrid", price: 100, scale: false},
    { id: 02, departure:  "Brussels", arrival: "La Habana", price: 500, scale: true},
    { id: 03, departure: "Madrid", arrival: "Bangkok", price: 1000, scale: false},
    { id: 04, departure: "Los Angeles", arrival: "Sydney", price: 1500, scale: true},
    { id: 05, departure: "Berlin", arrival: "Melbourne", price: 1100, scale: true},
    { id: 06, departure: "Jakarta", arrival: "Manila", price: 400, scale: false},
    { id: 07, departure: "Chiang Mai", arrival: "Phuket", price: 80, scale: false},
    { id: 08, departure: "Minsk", arrival: "Washington D.C", price: 100, scale: true},
    { id: 09, departure: "Bilbao", arrival: "Buenos Aires", price: 700, scale: false},
    { id: 10, departure: "Quatar", arrival: "Madrid", price: 300, scale: false},
]

console.log(flightInfo.slice(flightInfo.length - 5).map(e => e.arrival));
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var flightInfo = [
    { id: 01, departure: "Barcelona", arrival: "Madrid", price: 100, scale: false},
    { id: 02, departure:  "Brussels", arrival: "La Habana", price: 500, scale: true},
    { id: 03, departure: "Madrid", arrival: "Bangkok", price: 1000, scale: false},
    { id: 04, departure: "Los Angeles", arrival: "Sydney", price: 1500, scale: true},
    { id: 05, departure: "Berlin", arrival: "Melbourne", price: 1100, scale: true},
    { id: 06, departure: "Jakarta", arrival: "Manila", price: 400, scale: false},
    { id: 07, departure: "Chiang Mai", arrival: "Phuket", price: 80, scale: false},
    { id: 08, departure: "Minsk", arrival: "Washington D.C", price: 100, scale: true},
    { id: 09, departure: "Bilbao", arrival: "Buenos Aires", price: 700, scale: false},
    { id: 10, departure: "Quatar", arrival: "Madrid", price: 300, scale: false},
]

const getLast = (arr, number) => arr.slice(arr.length - number)

console.log(getLast(flightInfo, 5))
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply! Just tried it, im getting Array(5) [Object, Object, Object, Object, Object]as response unafortunately

Comment: What would you like to get?

Comment: Apologize, just realized values where INSIDE the objects. Somehow i thought i was gonna get the string values of determined key, i was wrong. Sorry I'm quite tired already. Thank you!!!